# Apache Virtualhost wrong destination folder

Tags: apache, redirect, web-config, virtualhost

I created a virtual host for on my Apache 2.4 Websever but if I am trying to load the URL the path is sometimes wrong and I get an error back by unknown reason.

I have the domain "test.com"

and my sites-available/default looks like this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot /var/www/test/
     ServerName test.com/

     <Directory /var/www/test/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If I am calling now the URL

```
"http://www.test.com/" or "www.test.com"
```

everything is fine but if I try to load for example "test.com" the server redirects me to

```
"test.com/test/"
```

and gives me a 404 Error. I don't understand why it is redirecting me like that on some URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the trailing slash

```
ServerName test.com/
DocumentRoot /var/www/test/
```

And change it to

```
ServerName test.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/test
```

Its redirecting you becuase the trailing slash is pointing to the `test` sub directory in the document root.

Since this is the only vhost config.  The following is from the apache documentation

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
# This first-listed virtual host is also the default for *:80
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias example.com 
DocumentRoot "/www/domain"
</VirtualHost>
```

Now all you have to do is add a server alias to specify www so that apache knows how to handle the event

Comment: now I still get the error if i am trying to load "test.com/" without "www" :(

Comment: try removing the slash from `DocumentRoot /var/www/test/` as well. since  test.com is the explicit server name handleed by this vhost config.  The other `www.test.com` is most likely handled by the `default` config if not defined by another vhost config.

Comment: I changed my default config now to: NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test
    ServerName test.com

     <Directory /var/www/test>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
 but i still have the 'www' issue and the default is the only one config

Comment: Add a SeverAlias to address www